# Seam Contexts replacement

Tags: java, jboss, xhtml, seam

Currently, I am upgrading my Jboss project from 5 to 7.1.1.  We are looking to phase out Seam, and therefore, cannot use org.jboss.seam.core.Contexts to inject values into xhtml files.  I am looking for a replacement, but am struggling to find something else.  Here is an example of us using Contexts:

```
Contexts.getEventContext().set("five",5);
```

then in xthml, that could be accessed via:

```
<div>#{five}</div>
```

and this would then display, 5.  What can I use as a replacement?

Thanks,

Update: also looking for a replacement for FaceletsRenderer, if anyone has suggestions...

Also, both of these things have to be done outside of the application thread.  If our application makes a rest call, I would like to be able to access the context in the rest call.  Seam was nice in that it allowed us to do this, but I know I won't have the same ability if I use something else, like FacesContext.